# Strange fire-breathing animal

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I drink from my tail.
>   I breathe fire.
>   I hate water.
>   Only fire can bring me back to life.

Who am I?

**Hint:**

> This is my first time here, I hope that you guys enjoy my very first riddle, and I don't feel like an old oil-lamp around these many bright-minded people.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a...

> Lamp with a wick, like a kerosene lamp?

*I drink from my tail.*

> One end of the wick is the tail

*I breathe Fire.*

> The fire burns on the other end

I hate water.

> Obviously, water can put it out

Only fire can bring me back to life.

> You have to start up the fire on the wick to light it up

Comment: Was going to write the same but the title says its any animal, that's why omitted the thought. :P

Comment: @Maniraj I think you should've tried this

Comment: @Ankit I would go with the instincts next time, rather that thinking biologically. :)

Comment: @Maniraj I'll keep that in mind

Comment: Actually, water won't put this out, but rather spread it in a usually spectacular way, which might be considered a different reason it hates water.